# Align objects into middle of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I am dealing with ADK and I have a problem. I use LinearLayout, and I want to put my objects into **middle and center** of layout.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

    <Button   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"

</LinearLayout>
```

Still it goes to the TOP CENTER or to left. Should I use something else instead of LinearLayout? Or is there special code for centering and middling?

Thank you for helping!

Note:  Unnecessary parts are removed.

Comment: Please post your layout code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` with nested `LinearLayout`. Put all your view into `LinearLayout` without applying centering and set `centerInParent="true"`.

But in your case just remove `layout_gravity` attribute from your views and add `gravity="center"` to the root view.

And also you forget to close your view's tags;)

So the final layout will be something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As a note, you should also make sure the RelativeLayout or the view parent has the width and/or height larger than the child, otherwise the child won't be centered.. I think this is a common mistake

Comment: Yep, LinearLayout with match_parent and gravity="center" works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider these things

1. Because LinearLayout just adds views one by one, your LinearLayout android:layout_width and android:layout_height should be "fill_parent" to show your views correctly
2. android:layout_gravity should be "center_horizontal|center_vertical"
3. Try adding android:layout_weight for your objects